# Is it possible to read a file "backwards" using Lua?

Tags: lua

Rather than reading the file from the front, would it be possible to read it backwards? So that the output is from the back of the file to the front of the file.

EDIT: Last line displayed first, not fully backwards.

Comment: fully backwards, so you get 'sdrawkcab'? or just last-line displayed first?

Comment: Does it need to be in O(n) time complexity?

Comment: @MarcB  last line displayed first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is based on the idea of @PaulKulchenko.
Yes, it's cumbersome :-)

Define function `io.linesbackward(filename)` in the `io` library:

```
function io.linesbackward(filename)
  local file = assert(io.open(filename))
  local chunk_size = 4*1024
  local iterator = function() return "" end
  local tail = ""
  local chunk_index = math.ceil(file:seek"end" / chunk_size)
  return 
    function()
      while true do
        local lineEOL, line = iterator()
        if lineEOL ~= "" then 
          return line:reverse() 
        end
        repeat
          chunk_index = chunk_index - 1
          if chunk_index < 0 then 
            file:close()
            iterator = function() 
                         error('No more lines in file "'..filename..'"', 3) 
                       end  
            return 
          end
          file:seek("set", chunk_index * chunk_size)
          local chunk = file:read(chunk_size)
          local pattern = "^(.-"..(chunk_index > 0 and "\n" or "")..")(.*)"
          local new_tail, lines = chunk:match(pattern)
          iterator = lines and (lines..tail):reverse():gmatch"(\n?\r?([^\n]*))"
          tail = new_tail or chunk..tail
        until iterator
      end
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
local filename = "your_file.txt"
print("--- backward: ---------------------------")
for line in io.linesbackward(filename) do
  print(line)
end
print("--- forward: ----------------------------")
for line in io.lines(filename) do
  print(line)
end
print("-----------------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but cumbersome. Lua API provides [seek](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:seek) function to set and get position in a file that read/write operations apply to.

So, you can use "seek" to read the file in small chunks from the end (for example, seek to `filesize-1024` position, read `1024` bytes, find all end-of-lines, print the complete lines and store the leftover) and continue doing that going backward to the beginning of the file. The main advantage is that you shouldn't spend much more memory than the buffer you are reading (where as if you are reading from the beginning, but want to print in the reverse order, you'd need to have the entire file in memory), but it's likely to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Not using standard library. But you can always read it from the start to the end by lines, store it in the table and then "use" it from the last line to the first.